# How to delay the Execution of Query function of Content Provider in case of OnQueryTextChange is executed

Tags: java, android, kotlin, search

Hello i am working on custom suggestion in my android application and i want to  delay the call  of Content provider Query method until the User finish typing the search text .If i use handler the return statement is executed and further the control goes to  Query function of Content Provider and when handler execute after 300 milliseconds the return statement has already executed and no further control is passed to Query method of Content provider.

```
override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String): Boolean {
            ViewCreator.setSearchText(newText)
                if (newText.trim { it <= ' ' }.isEmpty()) {
                    val objSearchQuery = SearchQuery()
                    objSearchQuery.searchInstance(appCMSPresenter)
                    objSearchQuery.searchEmptyQuery(
                        "",
                        appCMSPresenter.isNavbarPresent,
                        appCMSPresenter.isAppbarPresent
                    )
                    NO_RESULT_DATA = false
                }
            return false
        }
```

After execution this code it always reaches here

```
@Override
public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
    Cursor cursor;
    String query = ((constraint == null) ? "" : constraint.toString());
    if (query != null && query.length() != 0)
        appCMSPresenter.sendSearchEvent(query);
    try {
        cursor = getSearchManagerSuggestions(searchableInfo, query, 5);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.getCount();
            return cursor;
        }
    } catch (RuntimeException e)    {
        //Log.w(TAG, "runQueryOnBackgroundThread: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return super.runQueryOnBackgroundThread(constraint);
}
```

in Adapter class .What i am looking to do is that it should hold for 300 miliseconds in **runQueryOnBackgroundThread()** function before returning the cursor object.

Comment: can u add the code block with question ? if u return true the event will termed as consumed then after delay u can manually call query . not sure if will work or not ..

Comment: Share your codes.

Comment: It did not work by returning true either . it always calls the query() method of provider  whether it returns true or false . this is what the documentation says--https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener#onQueryTextChange(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

You can make this work simply using EditText, rather than using SearchView, Here is the code snippet you might want to use :

```
Timer timer1 = null;
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (timer1 != null) {
                    timer1.cancel();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                timer1 = new Timer();
                timer1.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (getActivity() != null) {
                            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Your Code Goes Here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }, 3000 /*Delay (In Milliseconds), Whatever you want to*/);
            }
        });
```

This will cancel your calls while user types, and afterTextChange will be called after user completes his/her typing. the best Typing delay you should use is 750 ms.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort man but need to delay the method inside My adater class as I have explained in question.